# Why JSX doesn't run while React works with no problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

First thing I'd like to say is that I'm obviously new to React. I did the set up like they said on their website, even for JSX.

When I paste their code it runs, but when I add JSX it doesn't work at all. I've got node.js on my computer too and I've retried it several times but no way. The console says: **Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.**

If anyone have any clue why this is not working it would be really helpful. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nova+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="back-body">
        <div id="main-canvas">
            <div id="root"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--React-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!--Babel-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS File:

```
'use strict';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Thank so much! :)

**EDIT**

I found out the problem after watching this video: **https://youtu.be/ahh65GQz74g**

Basically, I didn't set up Babel correctly as I wasn't placing the folders properly. Plus I left the Babel script in my HTML, which shouldn't be there. If someone else comes here with the same problem, I recommend to do exactly what that video says.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Because JSX isn't JS, something needs to transpile it back to React.createElement calls.

Comment: Yes I added Babel too, but still doesn't work.

Comment: But there's nothing to tell it what to do. You need type="text/Babel" at least, see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following attribute to your final script tag should do the trick:

```html
<script type="text/babel" src="./index.js"></script>
```

It's important to note that **this isn't a good practice for production environments**, as client-side compiling is slow and wasteful, so you should consider precompiling your scripts and setup your project accordingly.

**Update:** try modifying the source of babel to the following:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried but still nothing. I tried to put the script in the HTML file and it works but not while it's in the JS file. Can you recommend me any documentation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aZero updated the answer, using that version of babel it's working for me... follow up, are you using a local server or opening the html file directly in browser?

Comment: I'm opening the HTML directly in browser, yeah. I changed the script and doesn't work either.

Also, I did an npm audit becaouse I saw a problem, and the audit says "Regular Expresion Denial of Service". Could this be the problem?

Comment: yes, opening the HTML directly in browser could be the problem here... could you try entering the directory where you have the files through the command line and running the command "npx serve"? That will mount a local server on port 5000, so that navigating to http://localhost:5000/ in your browser should show you the app working correctly.

Comment: Nope, nothing at all. I opened it from the localhost and the result is still the same. Don't really know what the problem is, but I'm gonna try to solve it tomorrow. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I created this small gist replicating how I got your code to run: https://gist.github.com/lucasreta/4ad7d2513e4b139a3e2d93b0e1d46ba1

Comment: I found the problem. Basically I was being the problem hehe. I'm gonna edit the post now just in case someone else had this problem too. Thank you so much again for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding "text/babel" and its presets work as well

```
<script type="text/babel" src="./index.js" data-presets="es2015,react"></script>
```